# uri scheme property meaning

Tags: c#, .net

Perhaps it's not very practical question but still...

```
        var u1 = new Uri("esnode0:9200");
        var u2 = new Uri("esnode1:9200");
        var u3 = new Uri("esnode2:9200");
        var u4 = new Uri("esnode3:9200");
        var u5 = new Uri("esnode4:9200");

        var uriList = new List<Uri>() { u1, u2, u3, u4, u5 };

        if (uriList.Select(u => u.Scheme).Distinct().Count() > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("all URIs should be of the same scheme");
```

In this code I am declaring five URIs **without** URI scheme. In the end when I try to see do we have same URI scheme in list it turns out that... well, no. The scheme for this URI is the URI without port. I know that it can be easily fixed by prepending protocol to each of URIs. But what's the reason for such behavior? Isn't it safer to set URI to null in that case?

Comment: From wikipedia: A generic URI is of the form **`scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]`** . What you have is a legal URI with a scheme and a path. If you are committed to URIs, then there is a [definition of what a URI is](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), and you have no choice but to adhere to that definition.

Comment: @spender may I ask you how did you concluded that uri given contains scheme or path? if we adhere to format you said then either 1) path and port (: separator) or 2) the scheme is full uri? I mean we have clear separators for scheme(://), port(:), path, and query. If there is no :// we can safely assume that scheme is not provided. Anyway that's question of URI classification.

Comment: In a URI, the scheme is **non-optional**. This means that a parser will consume the scheme, leaving (in your case) only `9200` to be parsed into the following format: **`[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragm‌​ent]`**. The only way that `9200` can fit into this is as the `path` portion. Therefore you have a **full, syntactically complete** URI with a scheme and a path. That's the spec. If you don't like it, don't use it.

Comment: @spender thanks, missed that scheme is non-optional. Then it absolutely makes sense. My question was meant to understand why it works like that rather then find workaround so that it works like I want.

Comment: Got there in the end :) Glad to help.